# Setting file filter for AsyncFileUpload control

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, file-upload

I would like to know how I can set a filter for the AsyncFileUpload control. For example, I would like only *.gif and *.jpg images to be shown. How can this be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RegularExpressionValidator`

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexpImageE" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
                ControlToValidate="fupImageE" ErrorMessage="Only .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .tiff"
 ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF])$)">
                                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```